# Using "contains" as a way to join tables?

Tags: oracle, join, primary-key, contains

The Primary key in **table one** is used as in **table 2** but it is modified as so:

Primary key Column in **table 1**: `123abc`

Column in **table 2**: `123abc_1`

I.e. the key is used but then `_1`  is added to create a *unique value* in the column of **Table 2**.

Is there any way that I can `join` the two tables, the data in the 2 columns is not identical but it very similar. Could I do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN 
TABLE2
ON TABLE1.COUMN1 contains TABLE2.COLUMN2;
```

I.e. checking that the value in Table 1 is **within** the value in Table 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check only the first part of column2; for example

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2
ON INSTR(COLUMN2, COLUMN1) = 1
```

or

```
ON COLUMN2 LIKE COLUMN1 || '%'
```

However, keeping foreign key in such a way can be really dangerous, not to think about performance on large DBs.

You'd better use a different column in Table2 to store the key of Table 1, even adding a constraint.

Comment: Why did he get the upvote when I posted the answer first?